# Stop Google Sheets from creating link automatically

Tags: google-sheets-api

I am trying to write some text in Google Sheets, specifically some URLs. I need that because I am trying to explain to an agency the new tracking we are implementing.
I have the URL in a cell, and I went to have some caracters in red to highlight the changes, and leave the rest in black.
However, as soon as I modified my stuff in the formula bar, if I press enter or try to save the edit, Sheets automatically detects a link so it put everything in light blue and underlined, which is exactly what I don't want him to do.
I know there is a "stop detecting links automatically" thing in Microsoft Word and Google Doc but I can't find it in Sheets settings.
Any solution?

Answer (score 3):

immediately after typing the link after its been cast to a hyperlink, if you then press backspace a single time the conversion to link will be undone

Answer (score 1):

I've double checked the behavior of URLs in Google Sheets and I can see that even when you remove the hyperlink of a URL in a cell (via [Remove link](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/45893#change_link) option), it will still automatically reappear once you edit the cell of that URL.

**Recommendation**:

According to an answer from this post [How do I stop automatic hyperlinks in google sheets?](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/40020638), one of the community member have recommended to use a different format to the URLs to stop the cell from automatically creating hyperlinks. And this recommendation worked on my testing.

With that being said, I have crated a **workaround** using a custom [bound script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/bound#creating_a_bound_script), where it will automatically format all URLs (it'll add "//" at the beginning of each URLs) on a sheet and then it will visually hide the format for a cleaner look for your convenience. After that, the hyperlinks will no longer be auto-created on the URLs. The catch on this method is that users will need to remove the "//" at the beginning of the URLs to access them.

***Sample***

Sample sheet with URLs on Column A:

[image]

***Custom Bound Script:***

```
function onOpen() { //Creates a custom menu called "Hyperlink" at the top right of your spreadsheet file where you can run this script
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu('Hyperlink')
      .addItem('Remove Hyperlink', 'addFormat')
      .addToUi();
}

function addFormat() {
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
var range = sheet.getRange("A1:A").getValues(); //CHANGE THIS RANGE IF YOUR URLS ARE IN A DIFFERENT COLUMN
var text = "//";
  for(var x=1; x<=range.length;x++){ 
    if(range[x-1]=="" || x==1){ //If it is cell 1 (the title of the column) or if it is an empty cell, it will be skipped for formatting
    }else{
      if(range[x-1][0][0] == "/"){ //If a cell has been already formatted (//), it will be skipped
      }else{ //Formats new URL on the cell of Column (e.g. A)
        sheet.getRange(x,1).clearContent().setValue(text+range[x-1]).setFontColor("black");
        Logger.log("Done with "+text+range[x-1]+" on row"+ x);
        hideFormat(x); //function to visually hide the "//" on each URLs
      }
    }
  }
}

function hideFormat(row){ //Function to visually hide the "//" format at the beginning by coloring it to white font color
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getRange("A"+row); //CHANGE THIS COLUMN IF YOUR URLS ARE IN A DIFFERENT COLUMN
  var hide = SpreadsheetApp.newTextStyle()
      .setForegroundColor('white')
      .build();
  var richText = SpreadsheetApp.newRichTextValue()
      .setText(sheet.getRange("A"+row).getValue()) //CHANGE THIS COLUMN IF YOUR URLS ARE IN A DIFFERENT COLUMN
      .setTextStyle(0, 2, hide)
      .build();
  range.setRichTextValue(richText);
}
```

***After saving & running the script***, click the **Hyperlink > Remove Hyperlink** on your Spreadsheet:

[image]

***Here's the result:***

[image]

***Then, you can make any changes on the URL cells without hyperlinks being auto-created:***

[image]

Answer (score 1):

None of the existing answers actually provide a solution to the exact issue mentioned in the question, which is "[when] I press enter or try to save the edit, Sheets automatically detects a link so it put everything in light blue and underlined"

Pressing backspace as per @rexfordkelly's answer is only valid when the link is created during **editing** of the cell.

Here, the issue is that the link will be created when **saving** the cell *after* edition.

The only way I found to prevent this is to put the cursor outside of the text of the link.

Example:

Let's say `^` represents our cursor, and let this be our cell content:

```
my link: https://mywebsite.com
```

If you have your cursor e.g. here:

```
my link: htt^ps://mywebsite.com
```

or here (etc...):

```
my link: https://mywebsite.com^
```

the link will inevitably be created when saving the cell (i.e. hitting Enter).

However, if you have your cursor here (or anywhere else not on the link itself):

```
my l^ink: https://mywebsite.com
```

the link won't be created when pressing Enter.

Comment: Very cool, that makes a lot of sense, as to exactly where the event is triggered